# How Can I correctly write servlet url in JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, xml, tomcat, servlets

How should I write url in myscript.js to locate the servlet BeerSelect on server? I have tried many times but failed.

myscripts.js:

```
   var url= "../SelectBeer.do?ImageID=" + escape(itemName); // How can I write the url correctly?
```

index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="scripts/myscripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

web.xml:

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name> Ch3 Beer </servlet-name> 
    <servlet-class>com.example.BeerSelect</servlet-class> 
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name> Ch3 Beer </servlet-name> 
    <url-pattern>/SelectBeer.do</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

[image: directory tree]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried

```
        var url= "SelectBeer.do?ImageID=" + encodeURIComponent(itemName);
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/332888/1536382